# Is it possible to enable android multi-user from adb?

Tags: android, android-source, android-multiple-users, android-managed-profile

As stated in the [official document](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/multi-user#applying_the_overlay), it is possible to enable android multiple user feature at build time, but there is no document about enabling it on an exiting android image. Is there a way to enable multi-user on an existing device (e.g. using adb) considering that root access is available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can edit `/system/build.prop` on a rooted device and add multi-user support, then reboot:

```
fw.max_users=3
fw.show_multiuserui=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the property `fw.max_users` to your desired value can enable multi-user support. Something like `setprop fw.max_users $MAX_USERS`. Actually android itself reads this property to know if the device supports multi-user or not. You can refer to [UserManger](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/UserManager.java) source code to find how android reads the maximum number of users. The following snippet is copied from UserManager source:

```
     /**
     * Returns the maximum number of users that can be created on this device.
 A return value of 1 means that it is a single user device.
     * @hide
     * @return a value greater than or equal to 1
     */

    @UnsupportedAppUsage
    public static int getMaxSupportedUsers() {
        // Don't allow multiple users on certain builds
        if (android.os.Build.ID.startsWith("JVP")) return 1;
        return SystemProperties.getInt("fw.max_users",
                Resources.getSystem().getInteger(R.integer.config_multiuserMaximumUsers));
    }
```

Comment: This reads `@UnsupportedAppUsage`, which means not available to apps.

Comment: This is the API which will read when you queried from max users

Comment: This wasn't the question - and not even that getter can be called from an app.

Comment: This points that How we can change the No . of Users

Comment: `setprop fw.max_users 8` worked on my device, where 8 was the number of desired max users. I think @MartinZeitler misread your answer, maybe editing it may make it more clear.